# JNI Implementation

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

i've got a question regarding JNI Implementation.
I understood the concept of how to implement it in Java but what happens if you don't know anything about e.g the DLL.

Is there any chance to know which method to implement if you just have the DLL as a file? Something like reflection in Java?

Comment: in general case - no, you can try different reverse engineering techniques, but no obvious bullet proof method

Answer (score 0):

If you just have an arbitrary DLL and you want to call it from Java you need:

- to know the entry points exported by the DLL
- to write one or more native methods, and one or more corresponding JNI methods that call the exported entry points.

What you *can't* do is call arbitrary exported functions in an arbitrary DLL directly from Java via JNI. [You might be able to manage it with some JNA.]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Dll file and you want you use it but you don't know what method are implemented, that's no problem, but the problem is that Dll file is not compiled for java native interface(JNI).
but if Dll is created for jni, you can find its method using dependency walker or dll export or using some other utility after knowing the methods you can easily use dll created for jni.